# Disk size smaller than expected on new MacBook Pro

Tags: hard-drive

I have bought two new MBPs in the couple of weeks. One 256gb flash storage and the other is 1TB flash storage.

The 1TB reports a 1TB drive. The 256GB drive reports disk size of of 251GB.

Where did the missing 5GB go?

Comment: Try checking out this link: https://www.lifewire.com/drive-storage-capacities-833435

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a problem, at least not from the way you described it.  The OS takes up space plus there's other files stored on the drive.  You don't get access to all 256GB.

Comment: My Mac also reports a `256GB` drive as having `249.2GB` of space, and a `4TB` drive having `4TB`.  I don't quite believe the latter figure, I think it has rounded a number such as `3.96TB`.  I don't think it's a question of lost space, but of numbers being rounded for presentation.

Comment: As Apple says, the formatted capacity differs from the given one: "1GB = 1 billion bytes and 1TB = 1 trillion bytes; actual formatted capacity less."

Comment: Well, part of me wishes to point out I am not stupid. I am w2ell aware the the formatting takes up space. I wrote carefully but I shall try again: the 1tb disk says it has a 1tb disk in it. The 256 drive says it is only a 251 gb drive, with 221 available. Is that clear now? The picture of the flash drive says under it 251gb. The pic under the 1TB says 1TB!